# Accessing D365 CRM API's

Tags: xamarin.forms, dynamics-crm, o365-flow

We are trying to access data from D365 API's,

We are flowing the flow like Getting the token by using the Client ID and client secret

We are getting the token, New trying to access other app url's but getting the response are unauthorised

here the thing we are missing is we need validate the user. I am not getting exact api, where we can validate the user and then access the data.

This is the first API, we are calling

https://login.microsoftonline.com/ tenant ID /oauth2/token

passing client_secret, Client_id and grant_type

For that we are getting the token.

with that token we are not able access out D365 API's

But here where we need to login the user ? Any references ?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. See [Use the Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-microsoft-dynamics-365-web-api) for references. Since authentication seems to work and you have a token you'll have to show how you are trying to access the API to get help here.

Comment: I have gone through that documentation, the issue I am facing I am not getting how to authenticate User ? Any API is there for that after getting the Token ?

Comment: You can user Microsoft Graph API to authenticate User.